# What programs should I use if I want to create Android Apps?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been using Eclipse for a while but I feel like their are easier ways to create apps. I'm thinking about using Netbeans, but my main question is does Netbeans work with Android Devices and can I sell apps I make with it on the andorid app store?

Also, as for the 2d game engine, what should I use? I was thinking about Libgdx

(http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html)

I want something simple and not to complicated. 
And, is their anything else that I need to begin creating my apps?

Comment: I'm new here, so instead of downvoting me, could you be nice and please explain why instead of downvoting.

Comment: The reason why people are downvoting your question is because it is off topic - this is because it is asking for a recommendation for an external tool rather than asking for help with a specific problem. The stated reason why Stack Overflow considers questions asking for recommendations off topic is that they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a game, use LibGDX, also, nowadays i can suggest [GoDot](http://www.godotengine.org/wp/) Definitely worth a try, it's free, no royalty, good license. It is still missing a lot of documentation and tutorials, but with 2d you are good to go.

And yes, you can sell apps if you made it with eclipse (i recommend eclipse), or netbeans or anything. (haha unity....)

Application: Eclipse with installed Android SDK

Game: Eclipse with installed Android SDK, LibGDX library OR [GoDot](http://www.godotengine.org/wp/)

Comment: So downvote why? I took my time to answer the question, albeit i know the question isn't the best for SO, but why downvote my answer? .....

Comment: Ya, why downvote, His/her answer helped me a lot.

Comment: If I'm creating a game for android, do I NEED the Android SDK and LibGDX, or just LibGDX.

Comment: @user3185675 You need it, because libgdx uses it as a library.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic development and learning purpose Eclipse is the best tool for android.
There are advance development tool which makes development faster but requires some background knowledge of its base.
such tools are Android Studio(a Google tool), PhoneGap with HTML5 etc.
If you'r familiar with HTML,JS,CSS then go for phonegap.